# how to connect to the site with twitter

Tags: twitter

How to site login via twitter? I am using tweetSharp. I need to post some data to the site. This site requires twitter authentication

I can create request token:

```
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = twitterService.GetRequestToken();
```

But what is next?

Answer (score 0):

The TweetSharp GitHub page has code samples that will help you do what you are trying to do.

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp